# Nulls vs Guid.Empty in SQL Hierarchical Table

Tags: c#, sql

**Scenerio:**

I have a folder table with hierarchical records.  The ID of the row is of type GUID.  A ParentID on the tables stores the parent folder ID:

- ID (Guid)
- FolderName (varchar)
- ParentID (Guid)

**Question:**

What is the best practice for inserting a top-level folder?  Should I make the parentID column null, or create a "top level" record (ID = Guid.Empty) and use that ID for top-level folders?

Answer (score 5):

[`guid.empty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.empty.aspx) is not a SQL value. Make ParentID `null` for the root level.

You would have to hardcode `{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}` to select the root value, whereas SQL natively knows about `null`:

```
select * from mytbl where parentid is null
```

Also, look into SQL Server 2008's new [`hierarchyid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290(SQL.105).aspx) data type if you're building a Parent-Child table. It can save you a bit from having to build out the recursive CTE to traverse your tree.

Comment: We called these relationships "pigs ears" because of how they looked on logical ERDs.  If this is on Oracle, use CONNECT BY PRIOR id = parentid.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't make the column nullable. In the past I've made the top-level node point to itself as its parent, but an empty guid would be more or less the same as far as requiring a special check.

Answer (score 0):

I would either create a static guid that would represent the root, or assign the ID to the ParentID as a self-reference to signify the folder contains itself.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question directly, you should use a Null value in the Guid field.  There are two types of 1 to many relationships in Sql - that is 1 to many and 0/1 to many.

The correct implementation of this is to use a null value in the key field, to denote there is no relationship - in other words, it has a zero-to-many relationship.  The fact that the relationship is back onto the same table doesn't change this.

Don't use a zero-guid - this is bad practice in my opinion.  What you should do is capture any use of zero-guids in your code to make sure the null value is replaced.  I created a database function to translate the Guid.Empty value into a Database Null (for Sql Server, you don't specify a db implementation).  You could follow this idea for other database platforms.

Link here: http://www.ifinity.com.au/Blog/EntryId/81/Detecting-an-Empty-Guid-in-Sql-Server-in-T-Sql-Syntax

Answer (score 0):

In fact this is not just a C# question. Most of software developers faced off this decision.
My choice is using null as top parent. For the sake of,

Scenario 1: If we dont use not nullable on PARENTID column;

1-) First of all we should specify foreign key relation for the table among parentid and id columns

2) First record(Top parent)'s PARENTID must be equals to its own ID ,

so this is bad practice ,because this causes infinit loop in relation.

Scenario 2: If we use nullable PARENTID column;

1) Most DBMS's luckily allow null values on foreign key relations.

2) This allows first or any other records to be top parent row by just having null value on PARENTID.

So we dont need to create an infinite loop. 
Forgetting null check or forgetting special value no differs I think.
We already have a special value this is null value :)

Some of projects I conribute early used Empty Guid. And I see on reports items like "Please choose","Choose". Because its top parent (Empty Guid). So I need to check it.

Answer (score -2):

Using null for special value is a bad practice and an anti-pattern.

Null already has meaning in database which is *no value*. All database systems are programmed for this (via SQL standard which never evaluates operations with null to true (except for special case "is [not] null").

So choose the special value that is the best for your case and use it.

Comment: `null` in this case means that there is *no value* for `ParentID`. It is not only *not* an anti-pattern, but it's the best practice. This pattern is oh-so-common in data warehousing. So common, in fact, that the default flag for determining a root level in SSAS is `ParentIsSelfOrMissing`, meaning the `ParentID` is its own ID or `null`.

Comment: You contradict yourself - there is special value - self - for parent rows in the example of the function given. The fact that it accounts for nulls doesn't prove that it's a good practice to use it that way. The fact that some use it doesn't make it best practice either. Goto statement used to be common but people realized to stay away from it eventually. Given choices best practice would be non-null special value. Simple argument against null I already made is that it always requires special extra check like in the function from your example.